# Trouble passing selectors to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a series of modal dialogs with Back and Next buttons (to create a simple step-by-step quiz).  I'm trying to use a generic function to close any open modals and open the next (or previous) modal.  But I'm having trouble passing selectors to my function.

```js
function quizGo(name) {
    // closeModals();  // this part works fine
    var name = document.getElementById(name);
    console.log(name);
    //name.modal('show');
}
```

```html
<button id="quiz1Back" onclick="quizGo('quizModal0')">Back</button>
<button id="quiz1Next" onclick="quizGo('quizModal2')">Next</button>

<div class="modal" id="quizModal2" role="dialog">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're using Bootstrap modals to do this. The problem with your code is that Bootstrap requires a jQuery element to act on. Simply change this:

```
name.modal('show');
```

to this:

```
$(name).modal('show');
```

to make it work. The latter snippet just converts the DOM node to a jQuery element, on which Bootstrap can work. Alternatively, this one-line can also be used:

```
$('#' + name).modal('show');
```